# Delete file from Git

Tags: git

I'm still trying to fully learn Git, but after searching I'm still a bit confused. I removed the file from the Git repository using `git rm --cached` and the file remains locally. Upon pushing to the remote git repository and pulling it on the developmental server, the file that I removed is deleted. Could someone please suggest how to fix this?

Comment: fix what? what are you expecting

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1139762/1157054

Comment: Do you want to delete those files?

Comment: To make it clear, I'm trying to remove my wp-config.php from my repository as it is different on my computer and my development server. I want to have 2 different copies of the file, but when I ran git rm --cached, it kept a copy on my computer, but when I pulled to my server, the file was deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 areas you need to consider: the repository, the staging area and the workspace.

- **git rm**
  removes from the staging area and the workspace
- **git rm --cached**
  removes from the staging area only.  It only gets removed from the workspace when you commit.

The file still remains in the repository.  If you get a version of the repository before the file was removed, you will get the file back.

Comment: To escalate the example, you can erase the file from the whole history: `git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch FILES" HEAD`. Be careful with this!

Comment: To make it clear, I'm trying to remove my wp-config.php from my repository as it is different on my computer and my development server. I want to have 2 different copies of the file, but when I ran git rm --cached, it kept a copy on my computer, but when I pulled to my server, the file was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
git rm <Insert File name>
git commit --cashed <File name>
```

The first one removes it from the workspace and index. Cached will only remove it from the index. If you forget to commit then it will stay in the workspace.